# Django queryset return DurationField value in seconds

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

I have two models: `Post`, `Comment` (Comment has FK relation to Post).

Now I want to return all posts with theirs "response time". I get this response time in `timedelta` format. Can I receive it in seconds instead? I tried `ExtractSecond` but it is not what I'm looking for:

```py
base_posts_queryset.annotate(
    min_commnet_date=Min("comment_set__date_created"),
    response_time=ExpressionWrapper(F("min_commnet_date") - F("date_created"), output_field=DurationField()),
    response_time_in_sec=ExtractSecond(F("response_time"))
).filter(response_time__isnull=False).values("response_time", "response_time_in_sec")
```

This code returns following objects:

```
{'response_time': datetime.timedelta(days=11, seconds=74024, microseconds=920107), 'response_time_in_sec': 44}
```

What I want to achieve is basically call `.seconds` for each item in result queryset. I could do this in python, but mb it could be done on db level?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure can, but the exact mechanism may depend upon your database.

In postgres, you can use `EXTRACT(epoch FROM <interval>)` to get the total number of seconds.

To use this in Django, you can create a `Func` subclass:

```
class Epoch(django.db.models.expressions.Func):
    template = 'EXTRACT(epoch FROM %(expressions)s)::INTEGER'
    output_field = models.IntegerField()
```

Then you can use it directly:

```
base_posts.annotate(
    response_time_sec=Epoch(F('min_comment_date') - F('date_created'))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

As already answered here, it depends upon your database. As stated in Django documentation of [Extract](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.Extract) method:

> Django usually uses the databases’ extract function, so you may use any lookup_name that your database supports.

So for example with PostgreSQL:

```
response_time_in_sec=Extract(F("response_time"), "epoch")
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice solution!

One wrinkle is that I think there is a missing 's' needed to get this to work in Django 3

```
class Epoch(django.db.models.expressions.Func):
    template = 'EXTRACT(epoch FROM %(expressions)s)::INTEGER'
    output_field = models.IntegerField()
```