# How to get queryset with total seconds from sum of DurationField

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, timedelta

Suppose, I have a Django model called `MyModel` like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    event_started = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    event_duration = models.DurationField()
```

Now I want to get a queryset with the total seconds grouped by day. The following code returns the queryset with the total duration as `timedelta` instead of seconds:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

qs = (MyModel.objects
      .annotate(day=TruncDay('event_started'))
      .values('day')
      .annotate(total_duration=Sum('event_duration'))
      .order_by('-day')
      )
```

I want to include the total seconds instead of `timedelta` in the `total_duration` field of the queryset. How can I do that?

Comment: There is a decision: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75456437/9601060