# How do I convert an annotation from timedelta to seconds?

Tags: python, django

I'm annotating a queryset with time passed since the model was created:

```py
super().get_queryset().annotate(duration_seconds=timezone.now() - F("start"))
```

The result is a timedelta object, but I need it to be an integer in seconds. Calling `.seconds` is not possible in the expression, so how can I do this?

Comment: Maybe you can use: `Extract`   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#extract

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63905443/django-queryset-return-durationfield-value-in-seconds) might help